# Submit Button in Rails partial on same line as Cancel button in parent view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic rails form in a partial that is included in both my `new` and `edit` views.  Those views both have a `cancel` button, but with different links (new goes to index, and edit goes to show) so it has to go in the parent, not the partial.  I'd like the buttons rendered side by side, but not sure how to do that when one is in the form in the partial, and the other is not.

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question, in your post, when you say 
"I'd like the buttons rendered side by side". Those buttons that you are describing are the `create/update` button and the `cancel` button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the cancel URL as a [partial local variable](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables), like this (assuming your model is called `Post`):

```
# In new.html.erb

<h1>New Post</h1>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {post: @post, cancel_url: posts_path} %>


# In edit.html.erb

<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<%= render partial: "form", locals: {post: @post, cancel_url: post_path(@post)} %>


# In _form.html.erb

<%= link_to 'Cancel', cancel_url %>
```